# Unable to build Worklight project for "test" server (JDBC error)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Hello worklight team and devs!

We are done working on our development project and everything works fine in the local dev server (Tomcat).
Now we are trying to build the project to be deployed to a testing WAS ND 8.0.3 server.
We've been following the manual in the infocenter and modified each required file as needed (worklight.properties and application-descriptor.xml)

### We made this changes to the worklight.properties file:

```
publicWorkLightHostname=working.hostname.com
# http or https
publicWorkLightProtocol=http
# For default port leave empty
publicWorkLightPort=ourport
publicWorkLightContext=/worklight
wl.db.jndi.name=jdbc/WorklightDS
wl.db.type=DB2
wl.db.url=jdbc:db2:Worklight
wl.db.username=wluser
wl.db.password=passwd
```

We tested the jdbc source in the WAS console and it works perfectly.
We proceed to build the war, adapter and wlapp (ALL) and we get this error:

```
[2013-05-21 12:48:44] FWLSE4001W: Failed to resolve JNDI name: "jdbc/WorklightDS".
Application may fail to access the database in runtime. If building for remote server - ignore this warning.
[2013-05-21 12:48:44] FWLST0011E: ====== Worklight Project BPMWorklight-project-customization failed to start: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
[2013-05-21 12:48:44]             Activation failed. Bundle didn't start:C:pathto\BPMWorklight-customization.jar
```

This happens in the developer workstation and if we install Studio in the server, where the jdbc source is created, the same happens.
I guess that Worklight is trying to "obtain" a JDBC source in TOMCAT not WAS, but we are building for WAS, so the build fails and NO files are changed after the error. NO BUILD is executed.

We also tried to execute the build.xml with ANT in studio but we get this error:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Primary User\IBM\Worklight\LIS_SampleCollection\BPMWorklight\build.xml
BUILD FAILED
C:\Pathtofile\BPMWorklight\build.xml:3: Cannot find ../../common.xml imported from
C:\Pathtofile\BPMWorklight\build.xml

Total time: 62 milliseconds
```

You're help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks a lot!!

Best,

Nicolas E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you require is to deploy the updated-for-WAS .war file in WebSphere, you don't need to do any build operation in Worklight. After updating any file under the server\ folder in Worklight Studio (the Eclipse plug-in), the .war file is automatically being re-created.

The build operation is mainly for creating the binaries and deploying to Worklight Server (database) (again, when using the Eclipse plug-in).

So what I suggest is to:

1. First update application-descriptor.xml with your context root value in worklightServerRootURL, and keep your .wlapps on the side
2. Update worklight.properties and save them.

Now you have your app ready to deploy and the .war file ready to deploy.

1. Move to WAS, deploy the .war file
2. Hopefully things will work now, so you can load Worklight Console and deploy the .wlapp and .adapter files.

I don't know what you've read in the IBM Information Center, but you can also try going over the following training module from [IBM Worklight Getting Started](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#production).

- [Moving from development environment to stand-alone QA and production servers](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/10_01_Moving_from_development_environment_to_stand-alone_QA_and_production_servers.pdf)

---

**Notes:**

- The above is not so convenient, but it is A way to move from your
  development environment to another staging environment, or
  application server...
- The issue might also happen even after following my steps above, and this will indicate that the real issue is in your DB2 declaration in worklight.properties.

I will update this answer tomorrow with some insight regarding the possible DB2 declaration issue.

Comment: Idan, thanks a lot for your response!
We will try it out now and get back also tomorrow with our findings.

Comment: Idan, we were able to generate the *.war as instructed. But ran into a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683749/failed-to-deploy-worklight-adapter-in-worklight Can you take a look? thanks a lot for all your help!!

Comment: If your question (in this page) has been anwered, please mark this question as Answered. Thanks.